# EF4.1 Code First Complex Type as primary key

Tags: .net, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, primary-key, ef-code-first

I'm currently trying to implement the repositories for my domain objects with the RC of Entity Framework 4.1 and its code first approach.
Now I have a domain entity "Voyage" which has a unique identifier encapsulated in the type "VoyageNumber"

```
public class VoyageNumber
{
    private readonly string number;

    public VoyageNumber(string number)
    {
        Validate.NotNull(number, "VoyageNumber is required");

        this.number = number;
    }

    public string Id
    {
        get { return number; }
    }
```

Now I get an exception when i do this in the configuration of my DbContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Voyage>().HasKey<VoyageNumber>(k => k.VoyageNumber);
```

> The property 'VoyageNumber' cannot be
>   used as a key property on the entity
>   'Domain.Model.Voyages.Voyage' because
>   the property type is not a valid key
>   type. Only scalar types, string and
>   byte[] are supported key types.

and also when I try this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Voyage>().HasKey<string>(k => k.VoyageNumber.Id);
```

> The properties expression 'k =>
>   k.VoyageNumber.Id' is not valid. The
>   expression should represent a
>   property: C#: 't => t.MyProperty'

Do I really have to trash my VoyageNumber and replace it with a primitive type?

Comment: What is the exception message when you use this: modelBuilder.Entity<Voyage>().HasKey<VoyageNumber>(k => k.VoyageNumber);

Comment: Updated the question with the exception messages.

Comment: still the case in EF 6.1.3

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the limitation. Key members can be only scalar properties directly in the entity. Complex type is represented as complex property which is not supported.

Comment: What a shame, then I guess I'll give up on Code first, since I am not willing to give up the encapsulation of the primary key.

Comment: I wasn't clear. It is the limitation of Entity framework. Not only the limitation of the code first.

Comment: Is this still true in EF6? I'm getting the same error documented in the original questions so I assume nothing has changed but hoping some configuration option has been added that I'm missing.

Answer (score 2):

We can resolve it with the below. Hope it's helpful.

```
public class TestPaperResultId: ValueObject
{
    public TestPaperResultId(string testPaperId, string userId)
    {
        TestPaperId = testPaperId;
        UserId = userId;
    }

    protected TestPaperResultId() { }

    public string TestPaperId { get; protected set; }
    public string UserId { get; protected set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{TestPaperId}_{UserId}";
    }
}

public class TestPaperResult : AggregateRoot
{
    private TestPaperResultId _id;

    public TestPaperResultId Id
    {
        get => _id ?? (_id = new TestPaperResultId(TestPaperId, UserId));
        protected set
        {
            TestPaperId = value.TestPaperId;
            UserId = value.UserId;
            _id = value;
        }
    }

    public string TestPaperId { get; protected set; }

    public string UserId { get; protected set; }

    protected TestPaperResult() { }

    public TestPaperResult(TestPaperResultId id,
                           decimal fullmarks)
    {
        Id = id;
        Fullmarks = fullmarks;
    }
}
```

in dbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<TestPaperResult>()
                .Ignore(t => t.Id)
                .HasKey(t => new {t.TestPaperId, t.UserId});
 }
```

in Repository:

```
 public Task<TestPaperResult> FindTestPaperResultAsync(TestPaperResultId id)
 {
     return GetByKeyAsync<TestPaperResult>(id.TestPaperId, id.UserId);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For an isolated class you could do a read-only workaround by adding a "get" method to your DbContext that does a `SqlQuery<>` and maps the table to the class internally (the old-fashioned way).

I've worked up a minimal test-case here: https://github.com/timabell/ef-complex-pk

e.g.

```
public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{

    public IEnumerable<UberWidget> GetUberWidgets()
    {
        return Database.SqlQuery<WidgetSqlDto>("select WidgetId, Name from Widgets")
            .Select(dto => new UberWidget
            {
                UberWidgetId = new IdWrap { IdWrapId = dto.WidgetId },
                Name = dto.Name
            });
    }
}
```