# Entity Framework Core 7 - Composite key mapping to StronglyTyped Id object

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to map EF Core on a legacy oracle database who contains on each table a composite primary key of 4 fields  like Id1, Id2, Id3, Id4, Name ...

I want to have a DDD approach and don't have the database complexity in my Domain objects.
I have for example

```cs
 public class ExampleIdentity
 {
     public ExampleIdentityKey Id { get; private set; }    

     public string Comment { get; private set; }
 }
```

```cs
public class ExampleIdentityKey
{
    public string Id1 { get; set; } 
    public string Id2{ get; set; } 
    public string Id3{ get; set; } 
    public string Id4{ get; set; } 
}
```

How can I map this ?

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ExampleIdentity> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("Example");

    builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);
}
```

Every table in this oracle database have the same composite key.
I need to be able also to join easily between entity with that composite key, and for some entities i will need to use the SplitToTable.

I don't want in my domain to have on every Entity the 4 columns field defined, the only acceptable way is to store them on each entity on a strongly typed object like `public class Example2Id` and only keep reference between entities with those strongly typed objects

It's working fine when defining the 4 fields of the composite key directly on the entity itself, but as mentionned I don't want every of my entities to have those 4 fields.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522933/5265292 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/26981082/5265292

Comment: As a complement, it's really a composite key on 4 fields, and other table (entities in my domain also) will have the same 4 fields composite key. I want to map this into a complex Type MyComplexType Id on each entity. And referencing other entities with MyComplexType OtherEnitityId. The solution of base class would work for current mapping, but I want to avoid it, i don't want these 4 fields on each on my domain entities, and the joins (and reference) between entities will be too complex

Comment: Domain objects should not be used as your EF entities anyway

Comment: My underwhelming advice: accept your legacy system, go through the copy-paste hell of setting up all the necessary primary and foreign keys for each entity. If you can influence the database design, slowly refactor the database to get rid of the complex keys one by one.

Comment: Influencing the database design is my last option. I try to avoid it because it's a huge legacy with several application running on this database. But of course if I can change at least the table of my Domain to hold uuid and reference each other with that uuid, then the EF mapping would be easy